# How to to read the first part of the json feed - Windows Phone

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have been working on this for some time, i can read the last part, so everything from the square bracket to the end. But i can't read anything before that, when i put it in i Get a NullExceptionReference.

Here's the code I have got:

```
namespace WP7_ConsumeJSON
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(myButton_Click);
    }

    void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.ournu.co.uk/list.txt");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;
        try
        {
            ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Employee>));
            ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as ObservableCollection<Employee>;
            foreach (Employee em in employees)
            {
                string id = em.ServiceName;
                string dt = em.Destination;
                string tm = em.DepartureTimeAsString;
                listBoxService.Items.Add(id);
                listBoxDestination.Items.Add(dt);
                listBoxTime.Items.Add(tm);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }

    }
}
}
```

This is the feed result

```
{
"StopName":"Race Hill",
"stopId":7553,
"NaptanCode":"bridwja",
"LongName":"Race Hill",
"OperatorsCode1":"07645",
"OperatorsCode2":"7645",
"OperatorsCode3":"50701",
"OperatorsCode4":"bridwja",
"Departures":[
{
"ServiceName":"22",
"Destination":"Churchill Sq",
"DepartureTimeAsString":"1 min",
"DepartureTime":"01/01/0001 00:00:00",
"Notes":""
}
,
{
"ServiceName":"37",
"Destination":"Bristol Estate",
"DepartureTimeAsString":"1 min",
"DepartureTime":"01/01/0001 00:00:00",
"Notes":""
 }
 ]}
```

So what do i need to do modify in the code in order for me to be able to read the first part of the code.

```
 {
"StopName":"Race Hill",
"stopId":7553,
"NaptanCode":"bridwja",
"LongName":"Race Hill",
"OperatorsCode1":"07645",
"OperatorsCode2":"7645",
"OperatorsCode3":"50701",
"OperatorsCode4":"bridwja",
"Departures":[
```

Structure of the employee class:

```
namespace WP7_ConsumeJSON
{
public class Employee
{
    public string StopName { get; set; }
    public int stopId { get; set; }
    public string NaptanCode { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public string OperatorsCode1 { get; set; }
    public string OperatorsCode2 { get; set; }
    public string OperatorsCode3 { get; set; }
    public string OperatorsCode4 { get; set; }

    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string DepartureTimeAsString { get; set; }
    public string DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
}
```

Download project - [WP7_JSON.zip](http://www.ournu.co.uk/WP7_JSON.zip)

Comment: Please provide the structure of the employee class. You expect a collection of employees though the json object does not start with a collection. You could create a class that contains the proper fields for the first part of the feed aswell as the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a container class for the `ObservableCollection<Employee>` as to gather all that data!

```
public class RootContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    public string StopName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int stopId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string NaptanCode { get; set; }

    //Other root properties go here

    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the code like this:

```
void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;
    try
    {
        ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootContainer));
        RootContainer rootContainer = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as RootContainer;
        foreach (Employee em in rootContainer.Employees)
        {
            string id = em.ServiceName;
            string dt = em.Destination;
            string tm = em.DepartureTimeAsString;
            listBoxService.Items.Add(id);
            listBoxDestination.Items.Add(dt);
            listBoxTime.Items.Add(tm);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }

}
```

(I wrote the changes with Nodepad, hope I didn't make any error...)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have been able to put the first part in, with a reference. But can get the follow part to work, no reference.

ObservableCollection<Employee> rootContainer = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as RootContainer; (After the = part it shows an error)


        foreach (Employee em in rootContainer.Employees) (after the . it throws an error)

Comment: I have also created a link for the project. if that's helpful

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to change the type declared before the "=" sign... that's what I get for writing code with Notepad! Please check my changes

Comment: Hi, thanks After debugging, it stops after reading the URL, and throws an exception. "NullReferenceException" I think it is to do with the My button method.

Comment: You do not need the DataMember-Annotations, those are only needed for marshalling the objects to something else. NullReferenceException after ReadObject usually means, that it was not possible to map the input to the given class. The property for the employees is wrong it should be named Departures.